# What is the best way to resolve foreign key constraint error

Tags: mysql, synchronization, foreign-keys, mariadb, relationship

I have two tables related by a foreign key.

TABLE A:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `table_a` (
    `user_a_id` INTEGER NOT NULL, `remote_a_id` INTEGER NOT NULL,
    `user_b_id` INTEGER, `remote_b_id` INTEGER,
    PRIMARY KEY(`user_a_id`,  `remote_a_id`),
    FOREIGN KEY(`user_b_id`, `remote_b_id`) REFERENCES `table_b`(`user_b_id`, `remote_b_id`) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE RESTRICT
)
```

TABLE B:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `table_b` (
    `user_b_id` INTEGER NOT NULL, `remote_b_id` INTEGER NOT NULL,
    `name` TEXT, 
   PRIMARY KEY(`user_b_id`, `remote_b_id`)
)
```

Although the client maintains the relationships correctly in their tables, I do not know which table will remotely synchronize first on the server. If the client first synchronizes table_b there is no problem. But if the client synchronizes table_a and the keys are not in table_b, the foreign key restriction error will occur.

Currently I solve this problem in a transaction: If there is no (user_b_id, remote_b_id) in table_b, I insert a new record in table_b with table_b.user_b_id = user_b_id, table_b.remote_b_id = remote_b_id and table_b.name = null before inserting in table_a.

I would like to know if there is a better solution, for example using triggers or other mechanisms, that do not diminish the performance.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 0):

Why is the client controlling the synchronization?  That sounds like a long-term problem.

I would suggest that the client load data/changed tables into *staging* tables.  You can then do the appropriate updates *when all the needed data is available*.

Another alternative is to remove the foreign key constraint from this version of the database. It doesn't seem necessary and is getting in the way.

You could also handle this by using triggers.  The code you are running in a transaction could instead be owned by the database in a trigger.  But, triggers beget triggers.  You'll need similar logic when you actually decide to insert the rows with the non-`NULL` values in the second table.

Comment: The client can work offline on several devices at the same time (with the same user_id for his own records in all tables and a remote_id that I increment manually). The idea is to modularize the synchronization by separating one table from the other. I will also need the foreign keys to use the ON UPDATE CASCADE in some transactions.